# matTooltip not working in any routed components

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Tooltip **WORKS** on login component which is not loaded using loadChildren but **NOT WORKING** on Search component. The only difference is loadChildren is used to load search component but not for login component. Is there a way to initialize matTooltip on search component when loaded via route?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    loadChildren: () => import('./search/search.module').then((m) => m.SearchModule),
  }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**login.component.html**

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
    <input matInput  matTooltip="Username" type="text" formControlName="username" required autocomplete="username" data-cy="username" />
  </mat-form-field>
```

**search.component.html**

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Enter search term</mat-label>
    <input matInput  matTooltip="Search Term" type="text" formControlName="searchTerm" required />
  </mat-form-field>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatTooltipModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You are lazy loading SearchModule, so it is a completely separate module from AppModule. Is SearchModule correctly importing everything from AppModule and is SearchComponent declared in SearchModule? When dealing with multiple module issues you need to provide all of the affected modules.

Comment: you have to create a share module and import the mattooltip in that. then import share module in both app module and search module

Comment: @MylesMorrone Yes i have imported MatTooltipModule in SearchModule and added to constructor but no luck

Answer (score 1):

@Myles Morrone is correct, as he pointed out the "MatTooltipModule" import is missing in the SearchModule

**search.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatTooltipModule,
    ...
  ],
})
export class SearchModule {}
```